# merge columns and keep those that are not common in all

Tags: r

I want to combined four tables based on column `C`. However, if a row is found in one table but not the rest, then it should receive a `0`in the `V8` column. Se desired output. I tried normal `merge`however, then it merged rows that are found in ALL tables, which is not what I want. I want to include the rows that are also only found in a subset of tables.

```
> Ago1 <- Combined_59[,c("C","V8")]
> head(Ago1)
                                       C     V8
1   hsa-miR-21-5p_TAGCTTATCAGACTGATGTTGA 295649
2   hsa-let-7f-5p_TGAGGTAGTAGATTGTATAGTT 180249
3   hsa-let-7a-5p_TGAGGTAGTAGGTTGTATAGTT 165935
4  hsa-miR-21-5p_TAGCTTATCAGACTGATGTTGAC 141379
5 hsa-miR-21-5p_TAGCTTATCAGACTGATGTTGACT  81026
6  hsa-miR-99b-5p_CACCCGTAGAACCGACCTTGCG  66289
> 
> Ago2 <- Combined_60[,c("C","V8")]
> head(Ago2)
                                      C     V8
1 hsa-miR-21-5p_TAGCTTATCAGACTGATGTTGAC 304165
2 hsa-miR-99b-5p_CACCCGTAGAACCGACCTTGCG  95169
3  hsa-miR-92a-3p_TATTGCACTTGTCCCGGCCTG  73501
4  hsa-miR-21-5p_TAGCTTATCAGACTGATGTTGA 225277
5   hsa-miR-21-5p_TAGCTTATCAGACTGATGTTG  43357
    > 
> Ago3 <- Combined_61[,c("C","V8")]
> head(Ago3)
                                       C     V8
1  hsa-miR-21-5p_TAGCTTATCAGACTGATGTTGAC 311106
2 hsa-miR-21-5p_TAGCTTATCAGACTGATGTTGACT  38969
3  hsa-miR-30e-3p_CTTTCAGTCGGATGTTTACAGC  34218
4   hsa-miR-21-5p_TAGCTTATCAGACTGATGTTGA  29467
5  hsa-miR-99b-5p_CACCCGTAGAACCGACCTTGCG  25616
6  hsa-miR-532-5p_CATGCCTTGAGTGTAGGACCGT  24568
> 
> Ago4 <- Combined_62[,c("C","V8")]
> head(Ago4)
                                       C   V8
1  hsa-miR-21-5p_TAGCTTATCAGACTGATGTTGAC 6922
2   hsa-miR-21-5p_TAGCTTATCAGACTGATGTTGA 5456
3 hsa-miR-21-5p_TAGCTTATCAGACTGATGTTGACT 2325
4  hsa-miR-99b-5p_CACCCGTAGAACCGACCTTGCG 1019
5 hsa-miR-378a-3p_ACTGGACTTGGAGTCAGAAGGC  516
6  hsa-miR-30e-3p_CTTTCAGTCGGATGTTTACAGC  513
```

Output:

```
                                   C    V8_Ago1   V8_Ago2   V8_Ago3   V8_Ago4
  hsa-miR-21-5p_TAGCTTATCAGACTGATGTTGAC 6922     304165    311106    6922
  hsa-miR-30e-3p_CTTTCAGTCGGATGTTTACAGC 0        0         34218     513
  ....
  ...
```

Comment: Apparently this does not produce any rows with 0. There should be some that re unique to one table, thus producing a 0

Comment: Try  `Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by='C', all=TRUE), lst2)` and change the NA to 0`.  lst2 is the list of datasets

Comment: Maybe all=T in the merge-function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to read all the datasets in to a list, but if you have created individual dataset objects ("Ago"s).  Get the objects in a list using `mget` and then change the 2nd column name (in fact it is not needed.  There will be a warning message due to duplicated column names.  To avoid that, you could create "lst2" with changed column names).

```
lst <- mget(paste0('Ago', 1:4))
lst2 <- lapply(seq_along(lst), function(i) {
            x1 <- lst[[i]]
           names(x1)[2] <- paste(names(x1)[2], names(lst)[i], sep="_")
          x1})
res <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by='C', all=TRUE), lst2) 
res[is.na(res)] <- 0
```